Do I need to brute force the characteristic equation full of variables to find the eigenvalues?

Question 1 (25 points)
Let $$A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
 c&-k&-k\\
-k & c & k\\
-k & k & c
\end{array}\right)$$
where $c$ and $k$ are real numbers.
(a) Find the eigenvalues of $A$ in terms of $c$ and $k$.
(b) If $k\neq 0$, for each eigenvalue of $A$, find an associated eigenvector of $A$.

I am doing part a and I find it so difficult to solve the characteristic equation full of variables to find the eigenvalues.
$$\begin{vmatrix}c-λ & -k & -k\\-k & c-λ & k\\-k & k & c-λ\end{vmatrix} = 0$$
This results in the characteristic polynomial
$$-λ^3+3cλ^2-3c^2λ+3k^2λ+c^3+2k^3-3ck^2 = 0$$
Are there no other ways to do this? (Also, this is not an exam question. This is a slide of a lecture note that wasn't mentioned in the lecture)

There's a couple of other ways. You could let, say, $r=\frac{c}{k}$ and try to simplify the algebra before calculating the polynomial (you would have to look at $k=0$ separately, but that's pretty trivial here). Or you might notice something special about this matrix that tells you (at least) two eigenvalues will be the same, and what their corresponding eigenvectors are. Assuming this is for an exam, though, I wouldn't want to rely on spotting that - you are probably best off sticking with what you have and concentrating on finding a neat way to solve the polynomial.

Thanks for the answer and concern. This is not an exam question but a slide of a lecture note

Update: I solved it by factorization and x-substitution within the determinant. Thanks

note that the matrix is symmetric, hence diagonalizable. i doubt that diagonalizing it is less work than finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial though.

It is worth noting that the cubic formula can be used. Furthermore, since the matrix is symmetric (i.e. eigenvalues must be real), complex roots are discarded.

Sometimes using $\operatorname{tr}(A)=\sum \lambda$ and $\det(A)=\prod \lambda$ allows you to 'guess' the eigenvalues quite quickly since the trace and determninant can be found more easily

First write $A=cI_3+ kM$ where $M=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&-1\\-1&0&1\\-1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$.
Therefore :

$Sp(A)=\{c+k\lambda|\lambda\in Sp(M)\}$;

if $k\neq 0$, $E_{c+k\lambda}(A)=E_\lambda(M)$ for any $\lambda\in Sp(M)$.


Now reducing $M$ is quite easy. $\chi_M(X)=\det(XI_3-M)=X^3-3X-2=(X-2)(X+1)^2$.
Conclusion:  $$Sp(A)=\{c+2k,c-k,c-k\}$$
Use the second point to compute $A$'s eigenspaces.
